# Does "cafe" relate to the word "cafeteria?"

Tags: etymology, french

I know that the word *cafe* (referring to a place to go eat) stems directly from the same word in French meaning *coffee*, but what etymological connection does it have with the English word *cafeteria*? The two words have different connotations in English but I wonder if *cafeteria* and *cafe* share a closer background or snynonymity (either in English or Fench) or if one's usage predates the other's.

General reference resources vary about the details, especially as concerns the origins of *cafeteria*. [*Merriam Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cafeteria), with reference to *cafeteria* in the sense of "a restaurant in which the customers serve themselves or are served at a counter and take the food to tables to eat" and in the sense of "lunchroom", says the origins are

> American Spanish *cafetería* coffeehouse, from *cafetera* coffee maker, from French *cafetière*, from *café*.
>
> First Known Use: 1894.

*Merriam* gives the first known use of *cafeteria* as a adjective in the sense of "providing a selection from which a choice may be made" as 1908.

[*Random House* (at *Dictionary.com*)](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cafeteria), for noun senses similar to those given by *Merriam*, says the origin is earlier:

> 1830-40, Americanism; < American Spanish *cafetería* café, equivalent to Spanish *cafeter(a)* coffeemaker (< French *caf(f) etière*; *café* coffee + *-ière*, feminine of *-ier* -ier<sup>2</sup>; *t* apparently by analogy with words such as *bouquetière* flower seller, from bases ending in *t*) + *-ía* -ia.

[*Wiktionary*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cafeteria) is very loose about the date of origin for *cafeteria*, but provides a more detailed description of the language origins:

> (Mid 19th or 20th century) American Spanish *cafetería* (“coffeehouse”), from *cafetera* (“coffee maker”), from French *cafetière*, from *café*, from Ottoman Turkish قهوه (*kahve*) (Turkish *kahve*), from Arabic قَهْوَة (*qahwa*, “coffee”).

Comment: Yes. This is clearly explained at [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cafeteria).

Comment: Chaala good question! Well conceived, well-researched, well presented. **Upvote.** (In Telugu, which is not my mother-tongue, but my mother's first language, *chaala* is a commonly used word meaning 'very' -- I know only a very little Telugu, but 'chaala good question' is what we would say colloquially to mean 'very good question!')

Answer (score 28, accepted):

YES, the terms derive from Italian ***[caffè](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/caffe/)***

***[Cafeteria](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=cafeteria)***  is a more recent AmE term of Spanish influence:

[cafe](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cafe) (n.) :

> - 1802, from French café "coffee, coffeehouse," ***from Italian caffe "coffee"***  (see coffee).
> - The beverage was introduced in Venice by 1615 and in France from 1650s by merchants and travelers who had been to Turkey and Egypt. The first public café might have been the one opened in Marseilles in 1660.

***[Coffee](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=coffee&allowed_in_frame=0)***:

> - ***Introduced to England by 1650, and by 1675 the country had more than 3,000 coffee houses***. Coffee plantations established in Brazil 1727.
> - ***Meaning "a light meal at which coffee is served" is from 1774***. Coffee break attested from 1952, at first often in glossy magazine advertisements by the Pan-American Coffee Bureau. Coffee pot from 1705.

Cafeteria:

> - ***1839, American English, from Mexican Spanish cafeteria "coffee store," from café "coffee"*** (see coffee) + Spanish -tería "place where something is done" (usually business).
> - The ending came to be understood popularly as meaning "help-yourself" (as though café + -teria) and was extended to new formation with that sense from c. 1923.

(Etymonline)

Comment: You get my vote.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I'm unclear on the connection between "cafeteria" and Italian "caffe."  I'm assuming the idea is that Spanish "cafe" derives from Italian "caffe?"  So Italian --> Spanish --> English "cafeteria" and Italian --> French --> English "cafe?"

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime - it is a Mexican-Spanish influence on AmE in middle 19th century. From Venice the term spread throughout Europe in the 17th century. Then to America via Spanish colonies.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for... A friend of mine and I agreed that they must be related somehow (self-evident from the prefix "cafe") but because modern usage of the word "cafeteria" does not inherently imply that it is "a place to go get coffee" we were unsure. ["The ending came to be understood popularly as meaning "help-yourself" (as though café + -teria) and was extended to new formation with that sense from c. 1923"] was particularly illuminating. Extra kudos for citing historical background, thanks.

Comment: The Southern California supermarket chain Vons began as Von's Groceteria in the '30s, a self-serve, cash-and-carry outfit— relatively rare for a grocer of the era. I knew the outline of the history (having been roommates for a summer with a Von der Ahe), but had never put the *-teria* and *self-serve* together.

Comment: Josh, you should add that explanation into the answer.

Comment: Re the _-teria_ ending, in my part of the US state of Texas, the establishment that in other parts of the US is called a _laundromat_ is called a _washateria/washeteria_ (or _lavandaría/lavandería_ in the Spanish-speaking neighborhoods). I was surprised to see the [Google n-grams](https://goo.gl/2EaZ6R) results showing usage outside of Texas and as early as 1945.

Answer (score 4):

**Café**

The origin and history of 'café' in English seems at first blush to be straightforward, well understood and well documented. For example, [*OED*](http://oed.com/), in an entry not fully updated after its first publication in the 1888 edition, provides this account of the meaning of 'café' and its introduction into English from French:

> A coffee-house, a restaurant; strictly a French term, but in the late 19th c. introduced into the English-speaking countries for the name of *a class of restaurant*.  [Emphasis mine.]

Note the "late 19th" century attribution; presumably "late 19th c." means sometime before the 1888 date of first publication. (The previous, 1989 version of the entry uses the same wording; earlier versions of the entry are not available to me.)

*OED* follows with quotation evidence starting from 1802 (an earlier 1789 quotation is bracketed, indicating the English quotation includes *café* in French). The entry profile, however, suggests quotation evidence from 1763 ("first cited in Horace Walpole") was at one time part of the entry, but was corrected for the 1989 edition.

The 1802, 1815, and 1851 attestations of 'café' (not italicized) are likely cases *OED* considered "strictly" French. The [1870 attestation from D.J. Kirwan's *Palace & Hovel*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uiug.30112083970100;view=1up;seq=500), an account of an American's visit to London, most likely was *not* considered "strictly" French.

All that suggests 1870 was the date *OED* considers 'café' was "introduced" into English with the sense of "a class of restaurant". That date does not antedate the first *OED* attestation of 'cafeteria' in English, 1839. Nonetheless, the French term *café* could well have influenced the development of 'cafeteria'; the question is how and when, and whether other language influences were more prominent.

**Cafeteria**

'Cafeteria' has an oddly convoluted and difficult history in English. This history is *not* credited by *OED*'s treatment, which starts by misdating what they provide as the first attestation, from 1839. *Etymology Online* perpetuates that misdating to 1839, I surmise, but does not provide the attestation for the 1839 date given, and so is not easily faulted.

> **cafeteria**, *n.*
>   ....
>   **Etymology:** < American-Spanish *cafetería* coffee-shop.
>   orig. *U.S.*
>   A coffee-house; a restaurant, esp. now a self-service restaurant.
>
> 1839   J. L. Stephens *Trav. Russian & Turkish Emp.* I. 157   Every third shop, almost, being a cafteria [sic] where a parcel of huge turbanded fellows were at their daily labours of smoking pipes and drinking coffee.
>
> 1894   *Lakeside Directory* Chicago 2188   Cafetiria Catering Co. 45 Lake.
>
> [*OED*](http://oed.com/)

As mentioned, 1839 is not correct; the Stephens work was first serialized in 1836, in *The American Monthly Magazine*, v. 8. That serialization included several references to 'cafteria' ([pp 482-4, 486](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt/search?q1=cafteria;id=uc1.b5217006;view=1up;seq=505;start=1;sz=10;page=search;orient=0)), the context of which suggests these 'cafteria' were Turkish group lodgings where locals and travelers gathered to smoke, drink coffee, and sleep.

Additionally, but inconsequentially, the later publication of [Stephens work in book form](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015021284602;view=1up;seq=9) took place in 1838 (New York), rather than 1839. In that publication, 'cafteria' appears twice ([pp 35, 156](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt/search?q1=cafteria;id=mdp.39015021284602;view=1up;seq=9;start=1;sz=10;page=search;orient=0)), and the context suggests a use in the sense of 'a class of restaurant', that is, the same sense accorded to the later, 1870, English term 'café'.

**Antedating 'Cafeteria'**

The *OED* attestation from 1839, and the slightly earlier appearances of 'cafeteria' in works by the same author are not, however, the earliest appearances of the term in English. Earlier appearances suggest the word entered English not from American-Spanish, but rather from Spanish or Italian (Castel Nuovo is in Naples, Italy).

In [*The Eclectic Review* of 1833](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.aa0001463223;view=1up;seq=72), this mention is made:

> ...the Spaniard's lemonade is tasteless unless he can sip it in the accustomed Caffeteria...

And in [*The London Literary Gazette* of 1829](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=njp.32101076425402;view=1up;seq=716;size=150), in an exerpt from an 1828 work (*Reisen in Egypten, &c. Travels in Egypt, Libya, Nubia, and Dongola, Between the Years 1820-1825*, W.F. Hemprich and C.G. Ehrenberg), this:

> ...nor can I ever forget the five living Rolandos whom I saw standing in the caffeteria of Castel Nuovo...

Although neither of the attestations provides enough context to reliably ascertain the nature of the Spanish or Italian 'caffeteria', it seems clear that such were, generally, coffeehouses or "a class of" restaurants.

These attestations demonstrate that 'caffeteria' was in use in British English, with a sense at least similar to 'café', before it was adopted from American-Spanish into US English and began its progress toward the contemporary sense of 'self-service restaurant'.

**Another Consideration**

Noting the 55 (or more accurately, 58) year gap between the first and second *OED* attestations, I made shift to fill it. This was not so easily accomplished.

In an 1870 work, [*Italy: Handbook for Travellers*, by K. Bædeker](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=njp.32101032904193;view=1up;seq=333), I found this, where 'Caffeteria' is obviously Italian, in the section listing establishments of interest to tourists in Bologna:

> **Cafés.** ...*Beer:* Birraria e Caffeteria della Ditta Neviani in the side passage of the Piazza, E. of S. Petronio...

**Cafeteria in US English**

I found no uses of 'cafeteria' (or variants) in British or US English between 1839 and 1894. Numerous uses of 'cafetiere', meaning coffeepot, do appear, but do not seem on point for this answer.

Looking at the 1894 uses of 'cafeteria' did provide some interesting background, although the credibility of the claims made by the complainant in this March, 1894 newspaper article ([*The Inter Ocean*, Chicago, Illinois](https://www.newspapers.com/image/33775301/?terms=%22cafeteria%22), p 10; paywalled) has been undermined by the foregoing attestations of 'caffeteria' in English, possibly Spanish, and Italian:

> John Kroger, the proprietor of the "Cafeteria" Catering Company, has filed a bill in the Circuit Court to restrain W. H. Dittmer from using the name "Cafetier" in connection with the latter's restaurant. The bill says that the complainant adopted the name "Cafeteria" as a fanciful and arbitrary name for his business, although he says that the word has no descriptive meaning, and is not found in any language.

Also of passing interest is this April, 1894 ([*The Worthington Advance*, Worthington, Minnesota, p 6](https://www.newspapers.com/image/194675409/?terms=%22cafetiria%22); paywalled) description, which makes plain that the sense of 'cafeteria' as "a self-service restaurant" has been established:

> These new places are called cafetiria, or cafetier, or cafelakota, or buffetiria, or some other meaningless variation on a common name, and their motto is every man is his own waiter.

Answer (score 1):

What seems to be missing from all the other answers is the meaning of the suffix *-eria*.

In Italian, the [*-eria*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-eria) suffix can mean "a place connected with". So a *pizzeria* sells *pizza* and a *gelateria* sells *gelato*.

In Spanish, the [-ería](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-er%C3%ADa) suffix means "a place that sells something." So a *heladería* is an ice cream parlor and a *florería* is a florist.

So [*cafetería*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cafeter%C3%ADa#Spanish) (in Spanish) etymologically means a place you could buy and drink coffee. I don't know why there's an extra "t" in it; that is, why isn't it simply *cafería*.  It may be because [*cafetera*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cafetera) means *coffee-pot* in Spanish. Wiktionary thinks the extra "t" in *cafetera* was influenced by the "t" in *tetera* (teapot). And presumably there's an extra "t" in *tetera* because you *te* is a one-syllable word in Spanish, so you need to add a consonant when you add the suffix [*-era*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-era#Spanish).

Comment: What is puzzling, though, is how the word *cafeteria* in English ended up standing for restaurants of that particular kind (casual, self-service, usually provided by an employer or a school to its employees/students).

Comment: @jsw29: It's not clear to me how much of this meaning change happened in Spanish and how much in English. The second definition in [Spanish Wiktionary](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/cafeter%C3%ADa) is *restaurante de autoservicio* — self-service restaurant. (Whereas the first definition seems to be more or less synonymous with *coffee shop*.)

Answer (score 0):

Brazil exports coffee to England since the XVI century, maybe some portuguese words can be helpful to understand the question:

Cafezal: Coffee plantation (where farmers work)

Café da manhã: breakfast (which includes café)

Cafeteria: place where the workers eat, including "café da manhã"

Cafeteira: coffee jar

As a Portuguese speaker, all these words seem totally related.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELU. Please take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and consider how you might [improve your answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). As it stands, this sounds like opinion. Can you link to references that support your answer?

Comment: An analogy with another language may sometimes illuminate an aspect of English, but an answer which invokes such an analogy needs to make it explicit how it does that.